# Loop through URL parameters and add to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach, get

I am building a shopping basket with various products options. I have created my form with a get action:

```
<form method="get" action="">
<input name="category" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $category; ?>">
<input name="product_option_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $showProductOptions['id']; ?>">
<input type="text" maxlength="3" size="2" value="1" class="formqty" id="quantity_wanted" name="qty">
```

">

When this is sent the URL looks like this:

> menu.php?category=fruit-and-dessert&product_option_id=13&qty=1&product_option_id=14&qty=2&formadd=

What I need help with is to add the product option id and the quantity into a mySQL table. I have created this script but it doesn't add into the database? I don't get any error message either?

```
if(isset($_GET['formadd'])) {
foreach ($_GET as $productoptionid => $quantity) {
if(is_numeric($productoptionid) && is_numeric($quantity)) {
mysql_query(" INSERT INTO standard_basket SET session_id = '".$sessionid."', product_option_id = '".$productoptionid."', quantity = '".$quantity."'") or die(mysql_error());
}
}
}
```

Can anyone help? Many thanks!

Comment: what are you actually Doing ?? Insert or Update ?? Check syntax of query

Comment: Inserting into the database.

Comment: @Ashish: The OP's INSERT query is 100% correct. You can have INSERT & SET. I just fell foul of that one too.

Comment: Yaa.. It later clicked to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your foreach -

```
foreach ($_GET as $productoptionid => $quantity) {
   if(is_numeric($productoptionid) && is_numeric($quantity)) {
```

With your given url params, you would have the following values

```
$productoptionid => product_option_id
$quantity => 13

$productoptionid => qty
$quantity => 1

$productoptionid => product_option_id
$quantity => 14

$productoptionid => qty
$quantity => 2
```

so since your `$productoptionid` are strings (and they are not linked to your `qty`), your `INSERT` is never executed as `is_numeric($productoptionid)` is always false.

---

One way to do this would be to use the `product_option_id` as the input name array key `name="qty[<?php echo $showProductOptions['id']; ?>]"`-

```
<form method="get" action="">
<input name="category" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $category; ?>">
<input type="text" maxlength="3" size="2" value="1" class="formqty" id="quantity_wanted" name="qty[<?php echo $showProductOptions['id']; ?>]">
```

then your foreach loop could be -

```
if(isset($_GET['formadd'])) {
    foreach ($_GET['qty'] as $productoptionid => $quantity) {
        if(is_numeric($productoptionid) && is_numeric($quantity)) {
            mysql_query(" INSERT INTO standard_basket SET session_id = '".$sessionid."', product_option_id = '".$productoptionid."', quantity = '".$quantity."'") or die(mysql_error());
        }
     }
}
```

---

note: `mysql_` is deprecated. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php about how to update to `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you get the right values in your loop?
Because as the parameter list is, it would give you the product id at the first iteration and in every second the quantity (if qty is quantity...)

Comment: I think you have a point. Should the product option ID be a different name every time?

Comment: If the parameters are delivered as such, a workaround could be to have two vars outside the loop (q, id) and inside the loop you set them depending on the index - maybe change your var $productoptionid to $varname) and then if ($varname == 'qty') { $q = $quantity; } if ($varname == 'product_option_id') { $id = $quantity; } then every second iteration you store the value to the DB ... hope you get the logic.